# Merge columns of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've following dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B"])
df1["A"] = [1, 2]
df1["B"] = ["A", "B"]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "C"])
df2["A"] = [3, 4]
df2["C"] = ["C", "D"]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "C"])
df3["A"] = ["E", "F"]
df3["C"] = [0.1, 0.2]
```

I want to merge all three dataframes into single dataframe.
Expected Output:

```
df

 A B  C  D
 1 A
 2 B
 3    C  
 4    D
   E     0.1
   F     0.2
```

I tried using merge function . It appends only 2 dataframes and also appends characters to column names, which I don't intend to do.

```
df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='A', right_on='C')
```

I'd like to know if there is an alternative way or in build function to do this.

Comment: There is a mistake in `df3`. Should be  `df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["B", "D"])
df3["B"] = ["E", "F"]
df3["D"] = [0.1, 0.2] `

Comment: This mistake is present in all dfs. Your strings (the letters) need to be put in parantheses.

Comment: Yep, that and the letters in df3 are simply not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],sort=False).fillna('')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
    A   B   C   D
0   1.0 A   NaN NaN
1   2.0 B   NaN NaN
0   3.0 NaN C   NaN
1   4.0 NaN D   NaN
0   NaN E   NaN 0.1
1   NaN F   NaN 0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it

```
pd.concat((df1,df2,df3), sort=False)
```